# Validation in extbase using regex

Tags: extbase

I want to use validation of model properties in extbase via regex and using the following syntax:

```
/**
 *
 *@var string $telephone
 *@validate RegularExpression('/^[0-9]+$/')
 */
 $protected $telephone;
```

But I keep getting a validation error, irrespective of the value of $telephone variable.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do something like

```
/**
 *
 * @var string $telephone
 *
 */
 $protected $telephone;
```

in this case you only get integer values to var telephone.

the other way is to add the right validation syntax

```
@validate $telephone notEmpty, regularExpression(regularExpression="/^[0-9]+$/")
```

Comment: If the phone number starts with zero (e.g. `00498912345`), this would end up with `498912345` as integer representation. Find more details here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html